# Characters "ñ" and accents do not appear to send form

Tags: php, html, css, submit

I have a contact form on my website but when sending an email receipt with rare characters, for example the letter `"ñ"` with an accent used, it's not being sent.

Here is the code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>CONTACTO</title>
    <link href="estilo-pagina-css.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="izquierda-c">
      <section class="formulario">
        <form action="contacto/formulario/contacto.php" method="post">
          <label for="nombre">
            <span class="titulo-formulario">Formulario de contacto
              <br />
              <br />
            </span>
            Nombre:
          </label>
          <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" required="" />
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="ejemplo@correo.com" required="" />
          <label for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label>
          <textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required=""></textarea>
          <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CONTACTO.PHP

```
<?php
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
  $para = 'TUCORREO@CORREO.COM';
  $titulo = 'ASUNTO DEL MENSAJE';
  $header = 'From: ' . $email;
  $msjCorreo = "Nombre: $nombre\n E-Mail: $email\n Mensaje:\n $mensaje";

  if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header)) {
      echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');window.location.href = 'http://TUSITIOWEB.COM';</script>";
    } else {
      echo 'Falló el envio';
    }
  }
?>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

label {
    display:block;
    margin-top:15px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
.formulario {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family:Arial;
}
form {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;
}

input, textarea {
    width:380px;
    height:27px;
    background:#000000;
    border:2px solid #f6f6f6;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
}

textarea {
    height:150px;
}

#submit {
    width:85px;
    height:35px;
    border:none;
    margin-top:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: You have set char-set in the mail header as utf8 http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#108368 or use some ready made mailer like phpmailer

Comment: Hi I do not understand, you Might be more accurate? sorry

Comment: OK if you want to use the code the way you are using you need to set the email header as given in the above URL. phpmailer is an opensource mailing code using which we can send email and it has many functionality including the character set setting.

Comment: I Add $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

But still does not work, I've added to php